# Uncaught TypeError: event[type].add is not a function in D3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

getting the following javascript error while trying to implement the d3 example of mutual repulsion as shown in [d3Demo](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20110921/#6) .

I have included all the required JS files for the same viz. d3.js, d3.layout.js and d3.geom.js

Following id the JS code.

```js
var w = 1280,
    h = 800;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0)
    .charge(-60)
    .size([w, h]);

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

svg.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

force.on("tick", function() {
  svg.selectAll("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});

var p0;

svg.on("mousemove", function() {
  var p1 = d3.svg.mouse(this),
      node = {x: p1[0], y: p1[1], px: (p0 || (p0 = p1))[0], py: p0[1]};

  p0 = p1;

  svg.append("svg:circle")
      .data([node])
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", 4.5)
    .transition()
      .delay(3000)
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .each("end", function() { force.nodes().shift(); })
      .remove();

  force.nodes().push(node);
  force.start();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

I am getting this error **Uncaught TypeError: event[type].add is not a function** in **d3.layout.js** at line 323.

Following is the related code in d3.layout.js

```js
  force.on = function(type, listener) {
     event[type].add(listener); // line 323

    return force;
  };
```

I have included D3JS libraries in the following order:

```html
    <script src="../resources/js/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="../resources/js/d3.layout.js"></script>
    <script src="../resources/js/d3.geom.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. Could you post a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: I have updated the post to demonstrate the same.

Comment: Well you were using `d3.svg.mouse` instead of `d3.mouse`, but apart from that I didn't get any errors: https://jsfiddle.net/wo9do80y/ That said, I'm not sure what the thing is supposed to be doing.